# Django: Form validation for accepting strings with first letter in CAPS

Tags: python, django, forms, python-2.7

I have a model form defined in my application, and in one of my form fields, I want the users to enter their inputs, but with the first letter of their inputs in capital. If that's not the case, the application should throw an error and prompt the user to re-enter that particular form entry.

Is there an in-built Django form validator for implementing such a restriction?

PS: I am aware of the `capitalize()` method provided by `ModelForm` which stores the form field in database with first letter capitalized. However, this won't work for me, since I want to validate the input BEFORE form submission.

Comment: Why not just fix it with `capitalize()`? [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)?

Comment: @IanAuld I already mentioned this in my OP. I want the users themselves to enter the correct input in the form field. If nothing else, `capitalize()` would work. However, I wanted to know whether there's an alternate way to implement this constraint in my form.

Comment: Then use jQuery/client side validation. And for what it's worth you said you didn't want to do it not why you didn't want to do it which is a pretty important difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_capitalized(value):
    if value != value.capitalize():
        raise ValidationError('Invalid (not capitalized) value: %(value)s',
                              code='invalid',
                              params={'value': value})

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, validators=[validate_capitalized])
```

You can customize ValidationError for your needs. Docs: [validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/), [ValidationError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#raising-validationerror).

Answer (score 1):

You could use validators on the form or model fields, see the Documentation: [Using validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#validators) and [Writing validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/validators/).

Reference a simple callable that does the check and raise an exception.