# Django Rest Framework number type still pass validation from model

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

Hi i'm currently trying to write validation for my update API. i used the model fields in my serializer like so as i only want these fields to be update in the custom User model:

```
class UpdateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
      model = User
      fields = (
        'email', 'uid', 'nickname', 'eth_address', 'eth_private_key', 'evt_address', 'evt_private_key'
        )
```

My User model:

```
Class User(AbstractUser):

    uid = models.CharField(
        "uid", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(
        "Phone number", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(
        "Nickname", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Status", default=0)
    eth_address = models.CharField(
        "Eth address", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    eth_private_key = models.CharField(
        "Eth private key", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    evt_address = models.CharField(
        "Evt address", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    evt_private_key = models.CharField(
        "Evt private key", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    # deleted

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"

    pass
```

And here is my DRF update model view:

```
class update_profile(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication,)

    def update(self, request):
        user_data = request.data
        user = User.objects.get(uid=request.user.uid)
        serializer = UpdateUserSerializer(user, data=user_data, partial=True)

        if user_data == {}:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'code': 400, 'data': 'Invalid JSON object'})

        for key_name in user_data:
            if key_name not in ['email', 'uid', 'nickname', 'eth_address', 'eth_private_key', 'evt_address', 'evt_private_key']:
                raise serializers.ValidationError({'code': 400, 'data': 'Invalid input ' + key_name})

        if serializer.is_valid():
            updated_user = serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse({'code': 200,'data': updated_user.uid}, status=200)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'code': 400,'errors':serializer.errors}, status=400)
```

My input is as follow on POSTMAN:

```
{
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "uid": "dqwdqwd3123123",
    "nickname":"Alan",
    "eth_address": "dwdw",
    "eth_private_key": "fwef",
    "evt_address": "dwqdqwf",
    "evt_private_key": "dwqdqqd"
}
```

I want to test with conditions of wrong input so i input wrong email like `wrongemail.com` and it validated correctly:

```
{
    "code": 400,
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "Enter a valid email address."
        ]
    }
}
```

But when i try to do wrong input to other type like `"nickname": 4123414,` it still pass validation even when in the model i set `nickname = models.CharField("Nickname", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)` i don't know why the input value of number passed the validation without raising error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think most of the stuff you are doing here, like checking for correct fields, are done by the serializer itself. You just have to use `is_valid(raise=True)` and django will take care of returning the proper HTTP response (if you are using the default django error handler - read more [in the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data))

So here is how your view should look like:

```py
class update_profile(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = (FirebaseAuthentication,)

    def update(self, request):
        user_data = request.data
        user = User.objects.get(uid=request.user.uid)
        serializer = UpdateUserSerializer(user, data=user_data, partial=True)

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            updated_user = serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse({'code': 200,'data': updated_user.uid}, status=200)
```

However, I also think the nick example is actually correct. Number can be cast as string and that's what the serializer is doing -> it changes `4123414` to `'4123414'`. If you think about it, it's a totally valid nick. You should try other examples, like providing a negative number for `status`.

Comment: so is there anyway to check if it actually a string in the input json ? since sometime frontend will call the api with number value and they expected for it to return error

Comment: One sure way of doing this is writing a custom field validator, read more here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation

So you would have to make something that would raise validation error if not `is_instance(value, str)`. Should be simple.

Don't know about a better way to do that, but it sounds like it might be a popular problem, so I would do some googling before introducing a custom method.

Comment: Here is a similiar example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31540221/django-form-validation-for-accepting-strings-with-first-letter-in-caps

Comment: i decided to to write validation on the view side since everything in serializer  got converted to string, but thank for the explanation